# How to convert Varchar column to Numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I have a requirement to move varchar column data to Numeric but with two conditions.

1. All the alphanumeric value should migrate as null
2. All the decimal values should go as it is.

I wrote the condition as `WHERE data like '%[^0-9]%'`, it is working fine for all the records except for decimal.

Also I have values like `.001 abcd`, this has to be pass as null.

To summarize I need :

```
1) 1234 as 1234
2) 1.23 as 1.23
3) ABC as null
4) .ABC as null
```

Comment: HI !  try this,select * from yourtable WHERE ISNUMERIC(yourfield) = 1

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is the function nobody ever asked for and (pretty well) nobody needs. E.g. `1d1` and `£` are both considered numeric by that function but neither can be converted to `int` or `decimal()`. They're numeric because they can be converted to *any* of the numeric datatypes. Nobody ever wants to discover that specific fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is by default function in SQL Server **ISNUMERIC()** so, first of all Check your data value by that function,

```
Select ISNUMERIC(DATA)
```

Whole query is written as below,

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(data)=1 THEN CAST(data as decimal(18,2))
            ELSE NULL END as tData FROM DataTable
```

As per your question,first we have to convert with numeric with using **case**,which satisfies your first condition,another thing if the value is String than convert as `NULL`. In Above query both the condition has been taken care.

EDIT : If you are using **SQL SERVER 2012** or higher version then use
 `TRY_PARSE()`, then there will be no need to worry about using `CASE` too...

I have tried this,

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('63.36' as decimal(18,2)) got result 63.36
```

and

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('.' as decimal(18,2)) got result NULL
```

Comment: This answer is not literally true. It will be failed that `SELECT ISNUMERIC('.')  -- 1`

Comment: @Sagar I have a value +6000 in my varchar column, ISNUMERIC function is considering it as numeric, but ideally it is a varchar, it will throw error if I will try it pushing in numeric column.

Comment: @Ankit : found the best way,Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @Ankit : TRY_PARSE() is awesome feature provided in Sql server 2012 and later versions, please try my updated answer.

Comment: @SagarR Please try SELECT TRY_PARSE('+6000' as decimal(18,2))

Comment: @Ankit - so, to be clear. You're *not* looking to convert *any* values that SQL Server will happily convert to a `decimal()`. You want to *only* convert values that consist of digits and (optionally) one decimal separator.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes Exactly! Just need to move only integer values or decimal decimal values, rest everything should go as null, it should not allow any special character as well.

Comment: Also `TRY_PARSE ()` function also replacing the commas. For e.g 56,99 is becoming 5699

Comment: @Ankit: as per the MSDN "TRY_PARSE() function returns the result of an expression, translated to the requested Data-Type, or NULL if the Cast fails."

Comment: @Ankit might be worth editing your question with a clear spec (as per my comment, I "modestly" suggest) and the further examples where SQL Server will happily perform the cast but you do not want it to (such as your `+6000` example)

Comment: After discussing with my team and business, `TRY_PARSE()` is working great and they are fine with the data.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this fits your spec. It is quite verbose, but hopefully it breaks down the conditions sufficiently that it's clearly doing the correct thing or, if it isn't, that it's easy enough to modify:

```
declare @t table (data varchar(30))

insert into @t(data) values
('1234'),
('1.23'),
('abc'),
('.abc'),
('+6000'),
('1.2.3')

select
    CASE WHEN
        Possible = 1 AND
            (DecCheck = 0 OR
            SingleDec = 1
        ) THEN
            CONVERT(decimal(12,3),data)
        END
from
    @t t
        cross apply
            (select
                --Only contains the correct characters
                CASE WHEN not t.data like '%[^0-9.]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Possible,
                --Contains a decimal point? (Needs more checks)
                CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',t.data) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as DecCheck,
                CHARINDEX('.',t.data) as FirstDec --Where the first decimal point is
            ) p
        cross apply
            (select
                CASE WHEN DecCheck = 1 THEN
                    --Only contains one decimal point
                    CASE WHEN LEN(data) = FirstDec + CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(data)) - 1
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END
                ELSE 0 END as SingleDec
            ) d
```

Results:

```
data                           
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------
1234                           1234.000
1.23                           1.230
abc                            NULL
.abc                           NULL
+6000                          NULL
1.2.3                          NULL
```

I.e. one additional check you may want to use is that a decimal cannot be the first or last character in the string. That is easy enough to do by adding those additional checks into the first `CASE` for the `SingleDec` column.

Comment: Really Great answer,its an amazing work done by you,I must say you are the real hero in SQL.you pointed each and every thing in your query with core knowledge of functions. Hats-off to your work...

Answer (score 0):

try ISNUMERIC function,

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('abc')
SELECT ISNUMERIC('1.23')
```

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server (Version 2012, 11.0.5343)

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC('.') = 1 THEN <Field> ELSE 0 END
FROM
    <Table>
```

works fine ...

Answer (score 0):

Thre is [A blog post](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6423).

Try following

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            ISNUMERIC(data + 'e0') = 1 THEN CAST(data AS decimal(18,2))
        ELSE NULL END AS tData 
FROM 
    DataTable
```

Answer (score 0):

try ISNUMERIC function

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(Val VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES
     ('1234')
    ,('1.23')
    ,('ABC')
    ,('.ABC')
    ,('MJA')


Select  Val as OldValue,
        Case
        When ISNUMERIC(Val) = 1
        then Cast(Val as numeric(18,2))
        else null
        end NewValue
From    @MyTable
```

Output

```
  OldValue                                  NewValue
-----------------------------------------------------
  1234                                      1234.00
  1.23                                      1.23
  ABC                                       NULL
  .ABC                                      NULL
  MJA                                       NULL

  (5 row(s) affected)
```